# Python 2.7 - s.encode()

Tags: python-2.7, encode, radix

To change a string base, I know s.encode('hex') changes the string base to hexadecimal. 
What are the other bases that I can change to? Like, what would the code look like if I wanted to convert a string into base 2, 3, or 4?

Comment: Numbers have bases, strings have encodings.

Comment: Did you actually try running `s.encode('hex')` where `s` is a string? Apparently not, because it doesn't work...